# (Python 3) avoid printing comma at the end in print(variableName,end=',')

Tags: python, printing

I have a code that print x number of numbers. Firstly, I asked for the serious length. Then print all the previous numbers (from 0 to x).

My question is that: 
when printing these number, I want to separate between them using comma. I used **print(a,end=',')** but this print a comma at the end also. E.g. print like this 1,2,3,4,5, while the last comma should not be there.

I used if statement to overcome this issue but do not know if there is an easier way to do it.

```
n=int(input("enter the length "))
a=0
if n>0:      
    for x in range(n):
        if x==n-1:
            print(a,end='')
        else:
            print(a,end=',')
        a=a+1
```

Comment: `print(','.join([str(x) for x in range(n)]))`?

Comment: You already have the answer to your question, why are you asking a question you already know the answer to?

Comment: @roganjosh convert `x` to `str`.

Comment: @Douglas the OP's question is "is an easier way to do it", not "how do I do it"

Comment: @Douglas Sorry if the question upset you :)

Comment: Wasn't upset, just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic way of doing this is to use list comprehension and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join):

```
n = int(input("enter the length "))
if (n > 0):
    print(','.join([str(x) for x in range(n)]))
```

**Output:**

```
0,1,2
```

**Explanation:**

- **`','.join(...)`** joins whatever iterable is passed in using the string (in this case `','`). If you want to have spaces between your numbers, you can use `', '.join(...)`.
- **`[str(x) for x in range(n)]`** is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Basically, for every `x` in `range(n)`, `str(x)` is added to the list. This essentially translates to:

  ```
  data = []
  for (x in range(n))
      data.append(x)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A Pythonic way to do this is to collect the values in a list and then print them all at once.

```
n=int(input("enter the length "))
a=0
to_print = []  # The values to print
if n>0:      
    for x in range(n):
        to_print.append(a)
        a=a+1
print(*to_print, sep=',', end='')
```

The last line prints the items of `to_print` (expanded with `*`) seperated by `','` and not ending with a newline.

In this specific case, the code can be shortened to:

```
print(*range(int(input('enter the length '))), sep=',', end='')
```